# my NPM package is installed but not working?

Tags: npm, electron, electron-builder

I've installed the `electron-builder` npm package in my project via `npm install --save-dev electron-builder` and it successfully installed

Output from installing:
`up to date, audited 387 packages in 847ms`

However, when I try to run any commands with electron-builder I get this error:

`bash: electron-builder: command not found`

Why is this? Do I need to install globally or something? why does the cli not work?

(Also I am using a mac if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install `electron-builder` globally:

```
npm install -g electron-builder
```

Installing `electron-builder` with `--save-dev` means you can use `electron-builder` in NPM scripts, but only after installing with `-g` can you use `electron-builder` straight from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You install electron-builder  with `--save-dev` and it will install locally in  your project.

You can write the script in package.json to use it, for example:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "electron-builder -x -x"
  }
}
```